# Java - Creating Objects With ArrayList, Constructor Skipped 1st Iteration

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I am in the process of writing a program for a game of Blackjack. So far, I can create an object with a suit, value, and a value as a String. I am experimenting with different ways of implementing my classes into the game. Unfortunately, when I use a loop to create multiple objects in an ArrayList, when the first object in the list is instantiated with its fields the constructor is repeated twice. This is a problem because an array that checks for duplicate cards relies on each object calling the constructor only once. This only occurs when using ArrayList; using a single object works properly. Provided below are my two classes, driver, and sample output. Please ignore most of the comments, this was copied directly and most of them are notes for myself.

So why is it repeating? How can this be fixed? TIA.

**CARD CLASS**

```
public class Card 
{
    private final String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
    private final int[] VALUES = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    public String getSuits(int num) 
    {
        return SUITS[num];
    }
    public int getValues(int num) 
    {
        return VALUES[num];
    }
}
```

**DECK CLASS**

```
import java.util.Random;
//import java.util.Arrays;

public class Deck extends Card
{
    private String suit, valueString;
    private int value, valueNum, suitNum;
    private static int tot = 0;
    private static boolean[][] duplicateCheck = new boolean[4][13];//to see if suit/value pair has been used yet    //only fills up to 50 cards
    static int times = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    Card transfer = new Card();

    public Deck()//can the constructor just be a super() of the parent?
    {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(duplicateCheck));
        do
        {
            suitNum = rand.nextInt((3 - 0) + 1) + 0;
            suit = transfer.getSuits(suitNum);
            valueNum = rand.nextInt((12 - 0) + 1) + 0;
           // System.out.println("CARD BELOW");
        }
        while(duplicateCheck[suitNum][valueNum] );

        duplicateCheck[suitNum][valueNum] = true;
        //System.out.println(duplicateCheck[suitNum][valueNum] + ", "+valueNum + " "+suitNum);
        if(valueNum >= 9 && valueNum <= 11)
        {
            value = 11;
            switch(valueNum)
            {
                case 9:
                    valueString = "Jack";
                    break;
                case 10:
                    valueString = "King";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    valueString = "Queen";
                    break;
                default:
                    valueString = Integer.toString(valueNum);//not really needed
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(valueNum == 12)
        {
            if(tot + 11 > 21)
                value = 1;
            else
                value = 11;
            valueString = "Ace";
        }
        else
        {
            value = transfer.getValues(valueNum);
            valueString = Integer.toString(transfer.getValues(valueNum));
        }
        tot += value;
        System.out.println(valueString + ", " + suit + ", " + ++times);
    }
    public String getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
    public int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public String getValueString()
    {
        return valueString;
    }
    //put into place a method that plays a new deck after each hand
}
```

**DRIVER**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class DeckTester 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Deck temp = new Deck();
        ArrayList<Deck> t = new ArrayList<>();//problem has to do with ArrayList, it works with a single object

        for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++)//it doesnt display the first card
        {
            t.add(new Deck());
            System.out.println(t.get(x).getValueString() + " of " + t.get(x).getSuit() + " " + x);
        }

        //System.out.println(temp.getValueString() + " of " + temp.getSuit());
    }   
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
    //the first set of value and suit is from the deck class+a counter to show the number of objects before it

    5, Hearts, 1//notice the unused fields
    King, Clubs, 2
    King of Clubs
    4, Diamonds, 3
    4 of Diamonds
    9, Clubs, 4
    9 of Clubs
    9, Spades, 5
    9 of Spades
    4, Hearts, 6
    4 of Hearts
```

Comment: A few suggestions: Deck extends Card is quite strange; a deck is not a card. But it seems like your Deck class is really a Card, and your Card class is just a helper. Card doesn't have any state. Everything could be `static` there and there would be no need for Deck to extend it (and they could be renamed). You have logic in there for an ace equaling 1 or 11. You should probably focus on simply creating a deck to begin with, and have that logic in a Blackjack class later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is correct:
The first line printed comes from the   Deck temp = new Deck() when its 
constructor gets executed it printed 
    System.out.println(valueString + ", " + suit + ", " + ++times);

```
5, Hearts, 1  from temp constructor
```

this prints down here come from both the constructor 
    on each one and the print  System.out.println(t.get(x).getValueString() + " 
    of " + t.get(x).getSuit() + " " + x); within the for loop.

```
King, Clubs, 2  
King of Clubs
4, Diamonds, 3
4 of Diamonds
9, Clubs, 4
9 of Clubs
9, Spades, 5
9 of Spades
4, Hearts, 6
4 of Hearts
```

Now be aware that the constructor only gets executed only one time every time an object is created, it never gets executed twice your output print is misleading you.

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid for not realizing that. Thanks.

Comment: No need to be so harsh on your self, your card game shows you are in a good track. I just make one suggestion if you want to check for not having duplicate cards do this check outside the deck class, Leaving this check inside the constructor is pointless since every object doesn't know anything about the others and the array starts from fresh on every object., With the array created in the driver you can pass this array as a parameter to the constructor of the deck class so the class only creates cards that have not previously been created.